# AUTOSAR C++ Rule 3-1-5 - function definition in a class definition

Tags: c++, autosar

My code violates the following AUTOSAR rule:

Rule 3-1-5:

> **A function definition shall only be placed in a class definition if**
>
> 1. **the function is intended to be inlined**
> 2. **it is a member function template**
> 3. **it is a member function of a class template.**

A.h:

```
class A {
  public:
    void stop();
  private:
    bool x = false;
};
```

A.cpp:

```
void A::stop() {     // violates AUTOSAR 3-1-5
  x = false;
}
```

I tried defining the function with the keyword `inline`, but that didn't solve the problem.

The violation occurs only with functions that consist of only one line. This problem also occurs if the function is defined in a header file where no class exists (e.g. in a struct).

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Maybe they are trying to tell you that a single line function should be inlined, so it should be defined in the class body?

Comment: ***I tried defining the function with the keyword inline, but that didn't solve the problem.*** When you did that did you move the definition to the header? It would not change anything if you keep it in the cpp file.

Comment: @NathanOliver Putting the function definition in the header (and removing it from .cpp) has already solved the problem. Thanks! :) But why does AUTOSAR want me to do something like this? Will this reduce the execution time of the program as you know it from inline?

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. That was exactly the problem. I just added the keyword inline without removing the function from .cpp. Now I just moved the definition to the header, but I didn't use the keyword explicitly. As I understand it, the compiler does it automatically.

Comment: @KplnMoon It costs some time to call a function and return from one.  That can add up if you call the function a lot.  If you can inline it, then you remove that code which can increase performance.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, now it makes more sense to me. I just looked on another website, there it also says that the performance can increase. Thanks again!

Comment: @NathanOliver If you want, you can send your solution as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.